# Submitting the form to itself - Server self or Script name?

Tags: php, forms

I want to submit a form to itself. Now I give the filename directly i.e hard code it.

But I keep changing the filename often. So I decided to use some function from PHP.

On searching, I found out two functions:

`$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]` and `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` .  Both return the same values.

My question, what is the difference between the two & which of them is better to use?

Thanks in advance!!

P.S: I searched for such a question pretty well. No results turned up for me. Am sorry if this has already been asked !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: I found these functions from the manual. But I don't get the difference @Dugi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use either. *If anything*, you should use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` since it will include the query string parameters, but even that is unnecessary. A form with an empty action will submit back to itself per RFC 3986 standards.

Answer (score 0):

from documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

`$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]`

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in a script at the address http://example.com/test.php/foo.bar would be /test.php/foo.bar.

`$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]`

> The absolute pathname of the currently executing script.

Comment: Yeah, but both are going to return the same values, right? Even `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` will return /test.php/foo.bar